# Python Eve: Is there a way to avoid resource lookup passed through url in eve framework

Tags: python, get, endpoint, eve

Python Eve: Is there a way to avoid resource lookup passed through url in eve framework?

e.g. /people/(string:user_id)/hobbies

I want to avoid user_id lookup in the endpoint request where I will handle user_id field in a custom way.

Answer (score 0):

You can select which methods are allowed for each resource, or globally.

In this case you could limit the `GET` for `people` by setting the item `item_methods` property. For example, if you want to allow only `DELETE` for the item, you need to add the following in the [endpoint definition](http://python-eve.org/config.html#resource-item-endpoints):

```
'item_methods': ['DELETE']
```

The documentation says:

> item_methods:
>
> A list of HTTP methods supported at item endpoint. Allowed values: GET, PATCH, PUT and DELETE. PATCH or, for clients not supporting PATCH, POST with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header tag. Locally overrides ITEM_METHODS.

Comment: Hi GCW, I don't know whether I have explained my issue in a correct way to understand. I have created an api like example above now "POST" work fine but when it comes to "GET" request lookup always add 'user_id' for querying from resource which I want to avoid overall. Since my criteria for lookup is custom. My objective is to omit the additional lookup field "user_id" which is picked up from url path and added to lookup find queries. Is there any alternative.

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong. I was thinking you wanted to remove GET method. So you want to avoid query the items using the default ID lookup? Isn't the "user_id" you mention in fact mongo's object_id?

Comment: Yes, It is but not stored in the resource schema which I am querying or it is present under sub dict e.g.  {"_id":Ob to mongodb.jectId("someid"), department:"IT", employee_details:{"user_id":ObjectId("some user id"), "name":""}}.
Basically I want to avoid user_id lookup field for final query which is sent

Comment: Got it. But I don't know how to do that :/.